# Why doesn't the {% empty %} option show when no items available?

Tags: django, templates, tags

I have set up a "for/in" loop in a django template with an "empty" option, but when my view produces no items I get a 404 page instead of my "empty" option.

I have tried subbing in an "if" tag, but get the same result.

Template code:

```
{% for item in object_list %}
    <p>{{ item.desc }}
{% empty %}
  <p>Nothing scheduled
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
class ItemTodayArchiveView(LoginRequiredMixin, TodayArchiveView):
    login_url = '/admin/'
    redirect_field_name= 'redirect_to'
    date_field = 'airpub_date'
    allow_future= True

def get_queryset(self):
    destination = self.kwargs['destination']
    return Item.objects.filter(airpub_date__gte=date.today()).filter(destination=destination)
```

When the queryset is empty (i.e., there's nothing with that airpub_date) I want the template page to show "Nothing scheduled". Instead I'm getting a 404 debug page:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://xxx.xxx.xxx/items/atc/today/
Raised by:  items.views.ItemTodayArchiveView
No items available
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't even reach the template, because the view checks your queryset is not empty first. To disable this check, set `allow_empty = True` in the class - see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.allow_empty).